# Writing the name of Hashem

Tags: shemos-sacred-names, aleph-bet-letters

When writing sheim Hashem, why do people replace one letter with a *kuf*/ as in קל, יקוק, ה', צבקות, שקי etc.?

Comment: So that it doesn't have holiness and they can later destroy it

Comment: @DoubleAA: I think the question is why the letter Kuf is the replacement?

Comment: One of your examples (ה) does not use a ק. Is your question specific to the use of ק, or is it why are letters replaced at all? ( ping @GershonGold )

Answer (score 0):

Its the fastest way to turn the Hey into another letter. The leg is simply stretched a bit longer.

Comment: צבקות is replacing an aleph.  שקי is replacing a dalet.

Comment: I hear. I would be madcik that its agav the common name of Hashem...